# Do I need the bedrooms to let my spouse move in with me?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I recently bought a plot of land and built the manor  which, once semi-built, comes with two small beds. I have a bard, a driver, a steward, a housecarl, and two kids. Does this mean I don’t need the bedroom or will I be unable to let my spouse move in with me without it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want your spouse to live with you in a Hearthfire manor, then [yes, you do](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Marriage#Process):

> "*In the base game, a spouse will move into any house you own.
>
>   **For Hearthfire houses, you must have built a bed for your spouse**.*"

Do note that you don't need to own a house at all: marriage is possible without you owning property, in which situation you can live with your spouse (or '*betrothee*').